# Can a required script stop its parent script's execution?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, require

Is it possible––in a node app––for a required script to stop its parent script's further execution?

Let's say `a.js` requires `b.js`. Is it possible for `b.js` to stop the processing of `a.js`?

`a.js`

```
require('b.js')
// some other code that I might not want to execute
```

`b.js`

```
if (/* we do want `a.js` to continue */) {
  return
} else {
  // somehow stop `a.js` from being further processed
}
```

Ideally, the solution wouldn't involve spawning child processes :) Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Export a function that throws:

```
 module.exports = function() {
  // In case you want to end the parents execution:
  throw new Error("I just want to be mean");
 };
```

Then use it as:

```
  require("b.js")();
  console.log("this will never happen");
```

Comment: awesome! One thing though: if I'm not mistaken, that will also stop the required script's execution (which I want to prevent). Is there a way around this?

Comment: Hahaha understandably so. It's not the cleanest solution... but I'm working with ts-node/register and want to avoid the extra file that highjacks require. I'm hoping that, from my entry, I can require a package that stops the entry's execution, calls register, and then requires the entry (with an arg that tells the entry not to re-require the register-calling package. @jonas-wilms it sounds blasphemous, right?! But it's a fun experiment

Comment: I know it's a strange way to go about things... but it seems to be the only way to get rid of boilerplate with @babel/register & ts-node/register –– any tips would be so greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simpler than I realized at first:

`a.js`

```
const b = require('b.js')
// calling 'b' returns true if should terminate `a.js`
if (b()) {
  return
}

// the rest of script `a.js`
```

`b.js`

```
module.exports = () => {
  // run whatever,
  // return boolean (whether to further-execute `a.js`)
}
```